# Could localStorage use too much of a user's local drive space?

Tags: html, local-storage

I am learning about localStorage, and I understand that the limit is 5MB per domain.  The first thought that crossed my mind is that an average web user visits hundred of websites regularly.  If each one of these sites used their 5MB quota, the user could have multiple Gigabytes of storage on his disk dedicated to localStorage for his browser, which seems kind of crazy, especially for an ignorant user who might not be aware.

Now, I found my localStorage file in Firefox and it is only 2MB (and I've been recycling my user profile directory for years, so I expected it to be huge), so apparently either not many sites use it, or they clear it out often, or I don't know what.  But hypothetically it seems like a lot more space could get used, and in some cases wasted.

Is this a valid concern?  I couldn't find any discussion of this topic anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst people may visit many websites daily, most of them would *not* be regular. Google, stack overflow, facebook, gmail, youtube, x newspaper and 9gag may be an average casual browsing session. Provided websites are using local storage responsibly, that is storing data for a valid purpose and only when a user "registers" to a site (or specifically requests local storage) rather than every passing visitor, then I think it's a non-issue. It should be the responsibility of the browser to keep an eye on the storage size, and if necessary prompt the user to clear infrequently used data. Web browsers have been caching images from *every* website you happen to have visited in the history of the universe for a while now, I wouldn't say we've brought about a massive storage crisis. I would also question the impact of reaching a gigabyte of local storage anyway, given even budget laptops these days come with half a terabyte of hard disk space.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  The weird thing is that my cookies take up 1.5MB, compared 2.0MB for my localStorage.  I would have expected localStorage to be way larger than cookies, since I thought the point of localStorage was to offer more than cookies could, but maybe the "more" has to do with the types/format of the data stored, and not just the amount.

Comment: Aside from the points in my initial posting, I would add two further key distinct reasons for this. Firstly and quite simply, due to how "reliable" some web browsers can handle it, the more advanced features of HTML5 are not in widespread use. Localstorage is not something that "degrades gracefully", so to account for browsers like IE web developers need to create other solutions that happen to be cross-browser anyway, making a second localstorage solution redundant. Whilst gigabytes sounds excessive, I'm sure you'll see a quite a few more megabytes tagging along there into the future.

Comment: Secondly I would indeed agree with the issue you raised about data types. Localstorage is designed to hold small to moderate amounts of data, meaningful strings, numbers, etc. A bit like Cookies 2.0, it's not meant for "downloading the internet" with numerous high resolution images or the source code of an entire (complex) 3d game. The 2MB you have saved right now is probably all "crash proof" text you began typing into a textbox or details that could alternately be stored in a cookie, nothing overly special or space consuming.